# How to disable the original delete button after cloning also to do auto increment for the id textbox

Tags: javascript

I have clone rows code which include textboxes and delete button and I want to disable the original delete button only after cloning also i need the id textbox to auto increase when cloned

```js
function tablerow(addRow) {
  var table = document.getElementById('tablebody');
  var row = document.getElementById('tablerow');
  var clone = row.cloneNode(true);
  clone.id = "newid";
  var InputType = clone.getElementsByTagName('input');
  for (var i = 0; i < InputType.length; i++) {
    InputType[i].value = '';
  }
  table.appendChild(clone);
}

function deleteRow(delRow){
while (delRow.parentNode && delRow.tagName.toLowerCase() != 'tr') {
delRow = delRow.parentNode;
}
if (delRow.parentNode && delRow.parentNode.rows.length > 1) {
delRow.parentNode.removeChild(delRow);
}
}
```

```html
<button type="button" onclick="tablerow()">Add</button>
<table>
  <tbody id="tablebody">
    <tr id="tablerow">
      <td><input type="text" value="1" disabled/></td>
      <td><input type="text"/></td>
      <td><button type="button"/>Delete</button onClick="deleteRow(this)"></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: first thing to check here is, you are assigning the same `id` to every cloned element. `id` should always be unique

Comment: I made you a snippet.. Please update it with anything missing to have a [mcve]

Comment: Your code does not have a delete button.

Comment: thanks, i have edited with a sample of button

Comment: Please see my updated answer using your HTML (more or less)

Comment: Your delete event is on the wrong tag part. Anyway inline events are not recommended

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a mixed JS/CSS solution

```js
function tablerow(addRow) {
  var table = document.getElementById('tablebody');
  var row = document.getElementById('tablerow');
  var clone = row.cloneNode(true);
  clone.id = "newid";
  [...clone.querySelectorAll('input')].forEach(inp => {
    if (inp.classList.contains("del")) inp.classList.remove("first")
    else inp.value = "";
  })
  table.appendChild(clone);
}
window.addEventListener("load", function() {
  document.getElementById("add").addEventListener("click", function() {
    tablerow()
  })
  document.getElementById("tablebody").addEventListener("click", function(e) {
    var tgt = e.target;
    if (tgt.classList.contains("del")) tgt.closest("tr").remove()
  })
})
```

```css
.first {
  visibility: hidden;
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

```html
<button type="button" id="add">Add</button>
<table>
  <tbody id="tablebody">
    <tr id="tablerow">
      <td><input type="text" value="1" disabled/></td>
      <td><input type="text" /></td>
      <td><input  type="button" class="del first" value="Delete" /></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```